# Non freezing sleep in android app

Tags: android

I am programmatically creating some visual events, namely making an image appear when you click a button, it should then wait 500ms, then sweep the image off the screen in a swipe effect. However if I try and use Thread.sleep, it doesn't process the previous UI events before going to sleep, so in this case, the image should be set to visible, THEN it sleeps, but it sleeps before the image becomes visible. Also the loop to move the view is far too quick - I was hoping to use Thread.sleep to slow it down a little but looks like that won't work either.

What is a better way to do this?

```
View passImage = frontView.findViewWithTag(SearchConstants.PassImageTag);
passImage.setAlpha((float) 1);
frontView.setRotation((float)-10);

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (float i = 0; i > 0 - halfScreenWidth; i--) {
    frontView.setX(i);
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` in this case would send the `main event handling UI thread` to sleep, so the application freezes completely. Use a Timer of some sort, like a CountDownTimer.

Comment: or postDelayed with Handler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NEVER** use `Thread.sleep()`. If you do, you are blocking the current `Thread`. That means if you were to call `Thread.sleep()` on the UI `Thread` the UI would freeze and you couldn't interact with it anymore, just like you experienced. There are multiple options to schedule some task or event for the future. You can:

1. Use a `Timer`
2. Use a `Handler` with `postDelayed()`
3. Use the `AlarmManager`

---

## Using a `Timer`

`Timer` can be used to schedule a `TimerTask`. They are best suited to schedule tasks a few seconds to maybe a few minutes into the future.

First you have to write a `TimerTask`. This task will be executed once the time has elapsed. A `TimerTask` might look like this:

```
private class ExampleTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method is called once the time is elapsed   
    }
}
```

And you can schedule a `TimerTask` like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
ExampleTask task = new ExampleTask();

// Executes the task in 500 milliseconds
timer.schedule(task, 500);
```

---

## Using a `Handler` with `postDelayed()`

Using a `Handler` is pretty similar to using a `Timer`, but personally I prefer using a `Timer` as they are just better suited for jobs like this. `Handler` were originally meant to facilitate communication between `Threads` and other things, but they can also be used to scheduling a `Runnable`. First we have to define a `Runnable`, this is pretty similar to the `TimerTask`:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method will be executed in the future
    }
};
```

And now we schedule the `Runnable` to be executed in the future with `postDelayed()`:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Execute the Runnable in 500 milliseconds
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
```

---

## Using the `AlarmManager`

The `AlarmManager` is a system service and can be used to send an `Intent` at some point in the future. You can schedule this `Intent` for months or even years into the future with the `AlarmManager`, the only drawback is that you have to reset all alarms when the phone is rebooted.

You can get the `AlarmManager` like this:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

You also need to wrap the `Intent` you want to send in a `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SOME_ACTION);
...  // Setup your intent
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

And you can schedule the `Intent` to be sent at a specific `Date` like this:

```
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I've gone with the timer approach, however the problem is the TimerTask is executing on a different thread, and it has to move a view's X position - I get the exception 07-04 10:28:43.710: E/AndroidRuntime(1630): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Oh, in that case I suggest you use a `Runnable` instead of the `TimerTask` and call `view.postDelayed(runnable, 500);`. This posts the `Runnable` with a delay of 500 milliseconds to the correct thread so you can interact with the `View`.

Comment: Is your problem solved or are you still having trouble?

Comment: The problem is solved, the Runnable was exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!

Comment: i have already use timer task and handler but on both case getting stuck and freez application.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use an `AsyncTask`:

```
class ShowImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground( Void... args ) {
   Thread.sleep( 500 );
   showImage();
  }

}

void someMethod(){
  new ShowImageTask().executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );
}
```

Comment: elaborate please... as far as I understand, all scenarios you've shown above include Thread creation with more or less overhead. Why exactly is the `AsyncTask` sooo bad? TIA

Comment: You are creating a new `Thread` and block it immediately. It is essentially doing nothing but you are at the same time also blocking the executor of the `AsyncTask`. So no other `AsyncTasks` can run while this one is essentially doing nothing. You can set the executor to parallel execution but that can have serious ramifications like race conditions, long load times and general low performance which is why serial execution is the default. Additionally creating an `AsyncTask` is not really that cheap. All that overhead really isn't worth it if the task itself isn't doing anything.

Comment: So your solution could in the end cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: ok, so per default the tasks are running in `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR`. then they are queued. If I use `new TestAsynch().executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );` they are running in parallel. Does this have any potential gotchas?

Comment: As I said above, if you set it to parallel execution, you have a few problems: First and foremost you could run into race conditions. But you also have to consider that if you use parallel execution and you run multiple `AsyncTasks` at the same time that all of them will run a lot slower. This can even go so far that the tasks in parallel are much slower executed than if you would run them all serially. Unless it is really necessary one should avoid using parallel execution.

Comment: this is not something specific to AsynchTask. Any Thread has such problems. Anyway, thanks for the hint about not-default parallel execution. I was thinking, that ATs are running in parallel.

Comment: Parallel execution was default in previous Android versions. I think from Donut to Gingerbread but I could be a little off. And while it is true that all `Threads` may have these problems, the `AsyncTask` was designed to be easy to use in that regard. It manages a lot for you and normally you don't have to worry about any of those problems when running an `AsyncTask`. But again the main problem is that an `AsyncTask` blocks the execution of other `AsyncTasks`. And if you use parallel execution you get a whole load of other problems you potentially have to deal with.

Comment: And let's just be serious, you can't deny that an `AsyncTask` like you propose is semantically just an ugly solution...